# Call WCF Webservice function with predefinied URL GET Parameters

Tags: c#, windows, wcf

I'm currently implementing a webservice that is based on a huge contract-first xsd schema. I was able to convert the xsd's into c#-classes. Now I'm trying to implement the required functions into a wcf-webservice (side-note: this is my first WCF webservice). The specification requries following URL to call webservice functions via GET parameters:

http://b2b.example.com/?BuyersID=B127645&Password=secret&RequestName=GetProfileRequest

My class starts with following:

```
namespace VeloConnectService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute(InstanceContextMode = System.ServiceModel.InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = System.ServiceModel.ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class VeloConnectService : IVeloConnectService
    {
        public virtual GetProfileResponse GetProfile(GetProfileRequest request)
        {
            // TODO: GetProfile...
        }
    }
```

The types "GetProfileResponse" and "GetProfileRequest" are classes that capsules the defined fields from the xsd-files.

**Question**: How can I define that the URL can find the correct entry point? The URL should call the GetProfile function with the definied parameters filled in the "request".

Comment: This looks more like SOAP that RESTful... Can you give us more details on how you have set all of this up as WCF is by default SOAP?

Comment: I'm not very experienced in webservice development but WCF seemed the best way to implement this. If you have any other suggestions I'm open for new/better ways. I have an xsd schema which definies the contract-first communication between server and client. I have to develop the server. Sadly there is no implementation guide, just the xsd files :-/

Comment: SOAP is not RESTful. Therefore you don't have a URL that can GET the information from this call. You need a SOAP client (like WCF Test Client or your own) to call these methods. You then access the WCF Service via a call to where it is hosted and then call the methods (like RPC).